# How to make a python application that detects a color and when detected presses a button on the keyboard?

Tags: python, action, detection

I am trying to write an application that constantly checks for a color and when detected, presses the e button once.

```
import pyautogui
import time

color = (1, 72, 132)

def clicker():
    while True:
        x, y = pyautogui.position()
        pixelColor = pyautogui.screenshot().getpixel((x, y))
        if pixelColor == color:
            pyautogui.press('e')

def main():
    while True:
        clicker()
main()
```

I only got this but it does not work at all.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

To get a tuple of RGB colors at the current mouse position I use this

```
pixel = pyautogui.pixel(*pyautogui.position())
```